# batch download images from url with for

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to download 300 images from `site.com/folder/` using the following format: `1.png`, `2.png` ... `300.png`

Is there a way to do this inside a batch file or using the command prompt?

Comment: Reworded the question to be more succint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Numbered-Files Downloader 1.0

Here is a complete batch script that is doing exactly what you asked for. You don't need to download any executable files, this is 100% batch script and it should works on any (recent) Windows installation.

All you need to do is to edit the _**URL** variable (Line 11) and replace "example.com/folder..." with the actual URL of the files you want to download. After that, you can run the script and get your files.

- Note that in your URL, this string: **_NUMBERS**_ is a keyword-filter that will be replaced by the incremented numbers in the final download function.

All your downloaded files will be saved in the directory where this script is located. You can choose an other directory by uncommenting the _**SAVE_PATH** variable (Line 15).

Finally the following variables can be changed to configure the series of numbers:

_**START** : The file numbers starts with this value.
_**STEP**   : Step between each files.
_**END**     : The file numbers ends with this value.

---

### Leading Zeros

Currently, the counter doesn't support leading zeros.
EX. From Picture_001.jpg to Picture_999.jpg
But otherwise it should work fine for something like this:
EX. From Picture_1.jpg to Picture_999.jpg
I will try to find some time to add this option, it shouldn't be too difficult.

---

Feel free to modify & enhance this script if you need!

---

### Numbered-DL.cmd

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem STACKOVERFLOW - QUESTION FROM:
rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796990/batch-download-images-from-url-with-for


:VARIABLES

rem WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE FILES
rem "%~dp0" is a variable for the same folder as this script, so files should be saved in the same folder.
rem If you want to save the downloaded files somewhere else, uncomment the next line and edit the path.
SET "_SAVE_DIR=%~dp0"
rem SET _SAVE_PATH=C:\Folder\


rem DOWNLOAD THIS FILE URL
rem 
rem "_NUMBERS_" WILL BE REPLACED BY THE COUNTER
rem CURRENLY IT DOESN'T SUPPORT CHOOSING A NUMBERS OF ZEROS FOR THE COUNTER EX: 001,002,003... 
rem BUT IT SHOULDN'T BE TOO HARD TO IMPLEMENT, MAYBE ILL ADD THIS IN THE FUTURE.
rem 
rem SET _FILE_URL=https://example.com/folder/_NUMBERS_.png
SET "_FILE_URL=https://cweb.canon.jp/eos/lineup/r5/image/downloads/sample0_NUMBERS_.jpg"

rem FOR THIS EXAMPLE THE SCRIPT WILL DOWNLOAD FILES FROM "sample01.jpg" TO "sample05.jpg"
SET _START=1
SET _STEP=1
SET _END=5


:CMD_PARAMS
IF NOT [%1]==[] SET "_FILE_URL=%1"
IF NOT [%2]==[] SET "_SAVE_DIR=%2"


:PATH_FIX
rem REMOVE THE LAST CHAR IF IT IS "\"
IF [%_SAVE_DIR:~-1%] == [\] SET "_SAVE_DIR=%_SAVE_DIR:~0,-1%"


:DETAILS_DISPLAY

ECHO.
ECHO SCRIPT:     Numbered-Files Downloader 1.0
ECHO AUTHOR:     Frank Einstein
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO INPUTS
ECHO _URL:       %_FILE_URL%
ECHO _SAVE_DIR:  %_SAVE_DIR%
ECHO.
ECHO _START:     %_START%
ECHO _STEP=      %_STEP%
ECHO _END=       %_END%
ECHO.
ECHO.



CALL :DOWNLOAD_LOOP

ECHO.
ECHO EXECUTION COMPLETED
ECHO.
PAUSE
EXIT /B


:DOWNLOAD_LOOP

    SET FINAL_URL=%_FILE_URL%

    FOR /L %%G IN (%_START%,%_STEP%,%_END%) DO (

        rem REPLACE URL'S KEYWORD WITH NUMBERS
        SET NUM=%%G
        SET FINAL_URL=%FINAL_URL:_NUMBERS_=!NUM!%

        rem CUMSTOM BATCH FUNCTION FOR DOWNLOADING FILES
        rem 
        rem SYNTAX:
        rem echo CALL :DOWNLOAD !FINAL_URL!
        CALL :DOWNLOAD !FINAL_URL! !_SAVE_DIR!

    )


Goto :EOF
rem PAUSE
rem EXIT /B




rem FUNCTIONS

:DOWNLOAD

    setlocal

    SET "DL_FILE_URL=%1"
    SET "DL_SAVE_DIR=%2"

    rem EXTRACT THE FILENAME FROM URL (NEED TO FIX THIS PART?)

    FOR %%F IN ("%DL_FILE_URL%") DO SET DL_FILE_NAME=%%~nxF

    IF "%DL_SAVE_DIR:~-1%" == "\" SET "DL_SAVE_DIR=%DL_SAVE_DIR:~0,-1%"
    IF NOT [%2]==[] SET "DL_SAVE_FILE=%DL_SAVE_DIR%\%DL_FILE_NAME%"
    IF [%2]==[] SET "DL_SAVE_FILE=%~dp0%DL_FILE_NAME%"


    rem :BITSADMIN

    ECHO.
    ECHO DOWNLOADING: "%DL_FILE_URL%"
    ECHO SAVING TO:   "%DL_SAVE_FILE%"
    ECHO.

    bitsadmin /transfer mydownloadjob /download /priority foreground "%DL_FILE_URL%" "%DL_SAVE_FILE%"

    rem BITSADMIN DOWNLOAD EXAMPLE
    rem bitsadmin  /transfer mydownloadjob  /download  /priority foreground http://example.com/filename.zip  C:\Users\username\Downloads\filename.zip

    endlocal

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Windows 11 error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: I saw the comment from naXa in November so I fixed the script but got distracted and forgot to edit my response. I just noticed this so the script in my response should be working now.

Answer (score 10):

Wth `curl` like this:

```
curl -o "#1.png" http://example.com/folder/[1-300].png
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to download some batch codes from a file that can be created by this script if not exist, and of course you can add or modify what you want of urls in this file !

You can add your urls in the text file named ***Urls.txt***

Firstly, the script check for the text file named Urls.txt if exist in same location where this batch is executed and read from it the urls line by line to download them !
So, if you want to change those urls to yours, just change it from the text file Urls.txt not from the batch, i mean you can create a text file and name it to Urls.txt and put what you want as urls on this file line by line of course and let the script do its job

```bat
@echo off
Mode 110,3 & color 0A
Title Download file from web using powershell and batch by Hackoo 2017
Set "List_Urls_File=Urls.txt"
If not exist "%List_Urls_File%" Call :Create_Urls_File
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%List_Urls_File%"') do (
    Set "URL=%%a"
    Rem we set the Filename from the variable !url!
    @for %%# in (!url!) do ( set "File=%%~xn#" )
    Rem Check if the file name contains a dot "." 
    Rem If not we increment the counter +1 for file to be download
        ECHO !File! | FIND /I ".">Nul 2>&1
        If "!errorlevel!" NEQ "0" (
            Set /a Count+=1
            cls & echo(
            echo               Downloading file "File-!Count!.bat" from URL : "!URL!"
            Call :BalloonTip 'information' 10 '"Downloading File-!Count!.bat"' "'Please wait... Downloading File-!Count!.bat....'" 'info' 4
            Call :Download "%%a" "File-!Count!.bat"
        ) else (
            cls & echo(
            echo    Downloading file "!File!" from URL : "!URL!"
            Call :BalloonTip 'information' 10 '"Downloading !File!"' "'Please wait... Downloading !File!....'" 'info' 4

            Call :Download "%%a" "!File!"
        )
)
Explorer "%~dp0" & exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:Create_Urls_File
(
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/XvyhRzT6
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/QqnZ0MjQ
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/tHsKw15V
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/VCnTbLB6
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/3zUTrWUz
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/31auQeFz
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/xF0uXThH
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/uzsGQD1h
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/3TmVYiZJ
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/Ntc8SZLU
    echo https://pastebin.com/raw/jnpRBhwn
    echo https://www.virustotal.com/static/bin/vtuploader2.2.exe
    echo http://devbuilds.kaspersky-labs.com/devbuilds/KVRT/latest/full/KVRT.exe
)>"%List_Urls_File%"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
:BalloonTip $notifyicon $time $title $text $icon $Timeout
PowerShell  ^
  [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms') ^| Out-Null; ^
 [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing') ^| Out-Null; ^
 $notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon; ^
  $notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::%1; ^
  $notify.visible = $true; ^
  $notify.showballoontip(%2,%3,%4,%5); ^
  Start-Sleep -s %6; ^
  $notify.Dispose()
%End PowerShell%
exit /B
::*************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

try with [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat):

```
set "baseLink=http://example.org/folder/"
for /l %%a in (1;1;300) do (
   winhttpjs.bat "%baseLink%%%a.png" -saveto %%a.png
)
```