# Batch file to start download and track it

Tags: windows, batch-file, download

How do I create a batch file that downloads from https://www.sample.com/downloads/filename.exe and tracks it (echo %percent% complete . . .)?

Comment: You start a text editor, write the code, and save it. For downloading files with batch files you don't have many options. `bitsadmin` may be the safest choice, but it's complicated to set up.

Comment: @Joey, I'm looking for a way to do the job in pure batch code. THanks anyway!

Comment: Well, pure batch without external programs cannot download files, so you're done.

Comment: With a powershell command into batch file you can do it ! but in pure batch i don't think so ! perhaps with bitsadmin

Comment: @Hackoo May I see the powershell code?

Comment: @Anonymous  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796990/batch-download-images-from-url-with-for

Comment: @Anonymous Check my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 110,12
Title Download with BITS Transfer
set "URL=http://devbuilds.kaspersky-labs.com/devbuilds/KVRT/latest/full/KVRT.exe"
for %%a in ("%URL%") do set "SaveAsFile=%%~nxa"
powershell "Import-Module BitsTransfer; Start-BitsTransfer '%URL%' '%SaveAsFile%'"
Start "" "%SaveAsFile%"
```

Comment: Where will this download to, the current dir?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes in the current dir you will get the downloaded file !

Comment: Do you know any way you can use this to do a download from Google Drive?? That would help a lot